# C++ SFML Networking: Can't Establish a TCP Connection

Tags: c++, network-programming, sfml

Second Update: [ok, here's the wireshark results for what happens when I try to connect to a friend with this program, and it fails.  I've tried to remove his info, that's all the redacted lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNWHF.png)

Update: This works for all the computers on my local network, using local ip addresses.  It's when I try to connect to a remote computer with a public ip address that it has problems, now.  The client gets "cannot connect", after about 20 seconds, followed by "error number 3", where 3 is the error code provided by sfml.

I'd just like to know how to establish a remote connection.  I've looked at several other examples which seem to be identical to mine, and they work.

edit: I forwarded port 5000 to my computer on my router and gave that port to the client, along with my public ip address, in case if that was unclear.  Here's a screenshot of the rule I set up [http://i.imgur.com/Q8Kyu1E.png](https://i.imgur.com/Q8Kyu1E.png).  I also tried disabling the windows firewall entirely, with the same results.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "font.h"
#include "overhead.h"
#include "texture.h"
#include <iostream>

void render(Overhead &overhead, SDL_Rect *clip, Texture &texture, double angle, SDL_Point *centre, SDL_RendererFlip flip) {
    SDL_Rect render = { texture.textData.x, texture.textData.y, texture.textData.w, texture.textData.h };
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(overhead.renderer, texture.texture, clip, &render, angle, centre, flip);
}

void close(Overhead &overhead, Font &font) {
    TTF_CloseFont(font.font);
    font.font = NULL;
    overhead.closeOverhead();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    sf::Packet packet;
    sf::TcpSocket peer;
    sf::TcpListener listener;
    unsigned short port;
    std::string ip;
    sf::IpAddress ipaddress;
    char host;
    std::cout << "host (y/n): ";
    std::cin >> host;
    if (host == 'y') {
        std::cout << "port number to listen on: ";
        std::cin >> port;
        std::cout << "IP Address for local connection: " << sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "IP Address for remote connection: " << sf::IpAddress::getPublicAddress() << std::endl;
        if (listener.listen(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
            std::cout << "listener error" << std::endl;
        if (listener.accept(peer) == sf::Socket::Done)
            std::cout << "connection successful" << peer.getRemoteAddress() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "port number to connect to: ";
        std::cin >> port;
        std::cout << "you chose port number " << port << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ip address to connect to: ";
        std::cin >> ip;
        ipaddress = ip;
        sf::Socket::Status status = peer.connect(ipaddress, port);
        if (status != sf::Socket::Done) {
            std::cout << "cannot connect" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "error number: " << status;
        }
        else if (status == sf::Socket::Done)
            std::cout << "connection successful" << std::endl;
    }
    //other stuff
    peer.disconnect();
    close(overhead, font);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What ip address are you inputting in the client? Meaning is it of the type 90.50.90.50 or 192.168.1.100 ?

Comment: It's of the type 90.50.90.50, ie. the public IP address.

I tried switching the code to use the local IP address just now (using sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress()) and it actually works, although I don't think that'll be very useful for connecting to people outside of my home network.

Comment: 'Cannot connect' is not useful information. It is just a text string printed by your application in response to any of about a dozen possible failure conditions. You need to print the `errno`, at a minimum, or preferably the result of `strerror()`. Or call `perror()`. Until you provide that information your question is unanswerable.

Comment: I don't know how to implement strerror() or perror() or errno for this, but I did actually print the status message provided by sfml in my updated version.  It prints 3

Comment: If you look here, 3 indicates Disconnected. http://blaxpirit.github.io/crsfml/api/SF/Socket/Status.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the exact same issue while trying to host a server on my local network. It seems that, just like mine, your router does not allow NAT Loopback, i.e. access to your external IP via the local network (for more details about NAT Loopback, see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback)).
In fact, you will be able to access the host from a client located outside of your local network using your public IP address, but you will have to use your local address if you want to access it from inside the local network.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, it turns out it's not working for computers outside my network, actually.  It works for computers inside for my network though, like you said.

Comment: I just tried to run the socket example provided with the last release of SFML : I forwarded the appropriate port to my computer and tried to ping it via TCP using another computer, outside of my local network. The connection was successfully accepted...<br />

Comment: You should try to run this example program the same way you did it for your program and see if you get an error while attempting to connect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't realize that was there.  

One of my friends got a "connected" message, but I didn't see anything on my end, and he didn't get the followup messages he would have if things had worked properly.  The two other friends who tried to connect (and I tried to connect to them as well) didn't even get that far.  It's really weird and annoying, because as far as I know, we did everything properly.

I'm gonna try downloading Wireshark so I can see what might be going wrong

Comment: It would be a good idea indeed. Please let me know if you discover what caused this issue.